# Unity: Progress bar

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple presentation app and i can't figure out how to get the progress bar to work. basically the bar will have 7 points which is the same number as the presentation slide. I want when user is on presentation 5 to make the progress bar 5 points while changing the sprite of the current presentation to green and all previous to blue. and when user goes to the next i change point 6 to green and previous 5 to blue and so on. I have both Next and previous button. I'm trying to do it but i can't get the logic to work as i want.

1 - I can't seem to get the current slide index so i can switch the point to the green sprite

2 - there is one point that never get's affected in it and i can't know why..

This what i have so far.

```
public Image[] sliderDotsImages;
private int sliderIndex = 0;


private bool nextBtn;
private bool isPower;


public Sprite currentState;
public Sprite oldState;
public Sprite blankState;

private void Dots()
{
    if (sliderDotsImages.Length > 7 || sliderIndex < 0 ) return;



    if (nextBtn)
    {

        if (sliderDotsImages.Length >= sliderIndex)
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < sliderIndex;  i++)
            {
                sliderDotsImages[sliderIndex].enabled = true;

            //          sliderDotsImages[i].sprite = oldState;
            }

        }   
    }

    else
    {
        Debug.Log (sliderIndex);
        sliderDotsImages[sliderIndex].enabled = false;

    }
}

// Event attached to button 
public void Next ()
{
    if (sliderIndex < 0 ) sliderIndex = 0;
    nextBtn = true;

    // add point
    sliderIndex++;

    // Refresh dots 
    Dots();
}


// Event attached to button 
public void Previous ()
{
    if (sliderIndex > 7 ) sliderIndex = 7;

    nextBtn = false;
    sliderIndex--;
    Dots();

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `sliderDotsImages[sliderIndex].enabled = true;` be `sliderDotsImages[i].enabled = true;`?

Comment: I don't think so. I only want to enable till the index and not all dots

Comment: ok you are right. But how can i get the current index so i can switch it to green and older dots to blue?

Comment: `sliderIndex` is that value

Comment: true but how can i use it to switch the current dot to green sprite? it would be if (sliderIndex == ?? )

Comment: I don't know how green state vs. blue state is even *defined* given your current code.

Comment: i have 2 sprites, blue and green. the green state will switch on for example when user is in presentation 4. dot 4 will be green and dot 3 , 2 ,1 will be blue and other states greater than 4 will be blank because it's not reached yet. how would you do it?

Comment: If you have two sprites, then you need (surprise) *two sprite arrays*

Comment: i already have 2 sprite images. but how can i detect that im in current index. how can i use sliderIndex to change current dot image

Comment: You have more than "two" as you clearly have at least 8: seven green ones and a blue one.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: `sliderDotsImages.Length > 7` ← An array, implied to contain 7 items.

Comment: that's just for error handling...

Comment: That single line? Sure, but you *still have an array of sprites.* Does it, or does it not *contain seven items?*

Comment: it does contain 7 items but the check checks if its more than 7 which is never true...

Comment: Whether or not that check passes is irrelevant to my point. It is an array of 7 sprites. What are those sprites? They're green dots.  Awesome. *Where's the blue dot stored?*

Comment: no no... the array is just array of images. and i want to change the image sprite to green or blue. i already have the sprites. I want the current dot to be green sprite and all previous ones to be blue..

Comment: Your code currently makes no attempt to alter what sprite is currently being displayed. You're looping over that array and settings things to true or false. That's all your code does. If you want it to do something more you need to actually do *more.* Have you [looked at the docs yet?](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite-texture.html)

Comment: Im trying to change current index to green by using "     sliderDotsImages[sliderIndex].sprite = currentState;
" but it's not working i don't get it why. this should get my the current active dot and switch it to green

Comment: You have to refactor a lot of things here.  You're trying to represent a 3-state system with a boolean and a sprite reference. This is never going to work out well. Presumably `oldState` is the green image and `currentState` is the blue?

Comment: current state should be green and old should be blue. and blank must be the points that arent reached yet. and when previous button is clicked we set current to blank and -1 dot to current and older to blue etc..

Comment: I don't understand how the correct way need's to be done and that's why i asked question here....

Answer (score 2):

Egads it took a bit to figure out what on Earth was going wrong with the asker's question via the comments.  Now that I do understand what this class is supposed to be doing...here's how you fix it.

Ditch that loop, you don't need it, it's only making your problem *worse* because you don't need to look at the sprite for page 1 if you're on page 6. There's no way the sprite for page 1 needs to be udpated.  At all ever. NO, NOT EVEN THEN.

You have a 3 state system that needs to track "previously visited" "not yet visited" and "currently looking at." You can't do this with a single boolean. We can, however, use what we know about our system to cheat a little: the only dots that will ever need to be updated are the one we *were just looking at* and the one *we're about to be looking at.*

You also (twice) stated you didn't know how "to get the current slide index" despite having a variable that *literally is that thing:* `sliderIndex`.

Now then.

```
public void Next ()
{
    if (sliderIndex >= 6 ) return; //if on page 7, abort: there is no page 8
    sliderDotsImages[sliderIndex].sprite = oldState; //#1, #2
    sliderIndex++; //#3
    sliderDotsImages[sliderIndex].sprite = currentState; //#4
    sliderDotsImages[sliderIndex].enabled = true; //#5
}

public void Previous ()
{
    if (sliderIndex <= 0 ) return; //if on page 1, abort: there is no page 0
    sliderDotsImages[sliderIndex].sprite = oldState; //#1, #2
    sliderIndex--; //#3
    sliderDotsImages[sliderIndex].sprite = currentState; //#4
}
```

This is what this does:

1. We get the dot representing the page we were just looking at.
2. We set its sprite to old (blue).
3. *THEN* we change to the page we're about to be looking at.
4. We set that one's sprite to current (green)
5. If we went to the next slide, we also enable the image. We never need to disable it because once we've viewed a page, it's viewed.

Also, rather than doing weird stuff if our sprite index is out of bounds making its value a valid one, we prevent it from going out of bounds in the first place by returning early.

Comment: Hello. Thank you, however in the previous when i go back the dots that are in front should go back to blank because we didn't reach them yet cuz we went back

Comment: Put `sliderDotsImages[sliderIndex].enabled = false` between lines #2 and #3 in the Previous() method.

Comment: ok also one more thing. if i have button that takes me directly to slide 3 i need to refresh the progress bar to display the 3rd dot as green and dot 1 , 2 as blue . can i just set the sliderIndex to  = 3 ?

Comment: Same process as the next/previous: Update current dot.  Change index to 3. Update current dot.

Comment: sliderDotsImages[sliderIndex].sprite = oldState; 
  sliderIndex = 2; 
  sliderDotsImages[sliderIndex].sprite = currentState; this makes dot 0 blue , dot 1 blank and dot 2 green . it must be anything below dot 2 blue. i dont understand why dot 1 is blank

Comment: Also all upcoming dots stay blue

Comment: too many issues. because also it always starts at index 1 and not 0 so the first dot is never affected

Comment: @Alex at this point, start a new question. This behavior was not part of the original question. I have answered your original question.

Comment: @YvetteColomb At the moment it looks like it needs a *rollback* because 90% of the original question is gone leaving two and a half sentences.